# How can not push local git commit to remote

Tags: git, github, push, git-branch

I just want to commit local branch, and not push to remote. Then I can merge updates from remote branch. When push to remote, I can selectively avoid push this specific commit to remote, and others commits can be pushed to remote branch.

How to do this with git commands ?

Comment: keep this commit in separate branch

Answer (score 0):

"I can selectively avoid push this specific commit to remote, and others commits can be pushed to remote branch" -> No, you can't push "later" commits without pushing the "earlier" ones.  As @Heather says - put changes you don't want to push back to the origin on another local branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Run `git rebase -i HEAD~n` (n is uptil that commit that you dont want to push)

It will open a list of commits in your favourite editor. Pick the line that has `special` commit and move it to the end.

Save and Continue.

This will effectively bring the commit you dont bant to push to top. drop a branch just before this commit, and push to remote.

Hope this solves your problem!

Happy gitting!